# Port bind error on running jar with JMX parameters

Tags: java, jmx, jvisualvm

I am trying to profile my java application with jVisualVM using JMX on Ubuntu 18.04 with openjdk-1.8.0_222. But I am not able to start the java application with the required environment variables for using JMX as the communication medium.

The command I use to run my jar is -

```
java -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1098 -jar myApp.jar
```

I always get the following error -

```
Error: Exception thrown by the agent : java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 1098; nested exception is:
        java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed)
sun.management.AgentConfigurationError: java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 1098; nested exception is:
        java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed)
        at sun.management.jmxremote.ConnectorBootstrap.startRemoteConnectorServer(ConnectorBootstrap.java:480)
        at sun.management.Agent.startAgent(Agent.java:262)
        at sun.management.Agent.startAgent(Agent.java:452)
Caused by: java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 1098; nested exception is:
        java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.listen(TCPTransport.java:346)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.exportObject(TCPTransport.java:254)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.exportObject(TCPEndpoint.java:411)
        at sun.rmi.transport.LiveRef.exportObject(LiveRef.java:147)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.exportObject(UnicastServerRef.java:237)
        at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl.setup(RegistryImpl.java:213)
        at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl.<init>(RegistryImpl.java:173)
        at sun.management.jmxremote.SingleEntryRegistry.<init>(SingleEntryRegistry.java:49)
        at sun.management.jmxremote.ConnectorBootstrap.exportMBeanServer(ConnectorBootstrap.java:816)
        at sun.management.jmxremote.ConnectorBootstrap.startRemoteConnectorServer(ConnectorBootstrap.java:468)
        ... 2 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:387)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:375)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:128)
        at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createServerSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:45)
        at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createServerSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:345)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newServerSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:666)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.listen(TCPTransport.java:335)
        ... 11 more
```

As a first step I have checked if the port is being used which was not the case. Then I went on to try several other ports but with same results.

What might be going wrong?

Comment: How did you check port was not used? And is it just a java application? or any servers?

Comment: Are you running JBoss any way parallel?

Comment: netstat -pln | grep 1098. netstat -ao | grep 1098

Comment: Do you have any firewall?

Comment: No @Kris not running JBoss. I have tried few other ports as well.

Comment: Then it could be any firewall rules or anti-virus creating the problem. Is it a personal system?

Comment: A fresh install with no firewall rules. ufw is inactive as well. Not personal but a fresh install.

Comment: Can you try refining the netstat with "tu" flags too ? netstat -tulpn | grep 1098

Comment: No. that too doesn't yield anything